# How to visually analyze and track all source code and assets file size in a git repo?

Tags: git

I want to see the current state of repo to know what is the current size of all tracked files like HTML, PHP CSS, JS, Images, PDF and all others.

Would like to get view something like this

[image]

And then I want to track changes in all these files type to know how much data is being removed or added.

Is there a tool for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Git native tool, beside:

- [finding the largest files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9456550/6309)
- [getting the size of files over history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626019/6309)

But for a given checked out code base, you can run a tool like [draw-my-project](http://manland.github.io/draw-my-project/) (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/manland/draw-my-project)), which does include such a graph. It is only for javascript project dependencies analysis though.
So a regular tree file analysis tool (example [folder-size](http://www.folder-size.com/)) would be closer to what you are looking for, again for a given checked out code.

[image: http://www.folder-size.com/images/FolderSzie-Pie.png]